# How to normalize url's with parse_url?

Tags: php, url, parse-url

I'm trying to do very basic normalization and realize that to a large extent url normalization is an impossible task.

Regardless, different search engines return the same search results with different schemes, hosts etc. What are the most basic parts I need to collect and can you collect more then one part with parse_url to leave only the vital parts of the url?

Results 1: http://dogs.com
Result 2: http://www.dogs.com

Need t account for these kinds of inconsistencies that are possible and can be generated by different search engines

Comment: Question needs more clarification and some examples of "similar" URLs and what result you'd expect the normalization to produce.

Answer (score 1):

> Results 1: http://dogs.com Result 2: http://www.dogs.com

These 2 aren't the same: one is the main domain, the other is a subdomain. There's no guarantee that they serve the same content.

What you're asking for is basically impossible: any part of the URL is important and changing it may result in a different page.

That said, there's a `<meta>` tag for *`canonical`* which indicates the normalized URL of a page. Only that URL is (somewhat) guaranteed to be correct.

Also, you could just pull the content from pages and compare them. But, again, no guarantees.